# Solidity function overloading behavior

Tags: ethereum, solidity, contract

My contract like this, the question is why `foo(uint256 n)` not working(no value return). If the contract just hava `foo(uint256 n)`, it works.

```
contract OverloadContract {
// working
function foo(uint256 n, uint256 m) public pure returns (uint256) {
    return n + m;
}

// not working ?
function foo(uint256 n) public pure returns (uint256) {
    return n;
}

// working
function foo() public pure returns (uint256) {
    return 1;
}

// working
function foo(uint256 i, uint256 n, uint256 m) public pure returns (uint256) {
    return i + n + m;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you testing this in Remix? I can reproduce it there, but when I call the function directly via `eth_call` (JSON-RPC interface), the function is working properly.

Comment: In fact, in Remix, testing against a local `ganache` instance, I can see the right value coming back in the network tab, so this looks like a bug in the UI layer.

Comment: I'd recommend filing an issue: https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide.

Comment: Yes, I write this in Remix-ide, Thanks @smarx, I'll filling an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Bug is fixed by ethereum/remix#864 and will be shipped with Remix 0.7.

Link: https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/issues/1460